# Non capturing group java regex

Tags: java, regex

I saw this post [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)

And i figured that the following would work, but it doesn't...

I have a String `"Game No : 432543254 \n"`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:Game No : )[0-9]*?(\n)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(curr);
m.find();
System.out.print(m.group());
```

But the code above prints the entire string, not just the numbers i want

Comment: It prints the entire string because you're telling it to. `m.group()` refers to the entire match. If you're only interested in a portion of the matched text, use a capture group, e.g. `Game No : ([0-9]*)` and then `print(m.group(1))`.

Comment: Just because `Game No` is in a non-capturing group, doesn't mean that  it isn't part of the match. You want a lookbehind if you want to exclude it from the match.

Comment: What makes you think that it should print only numbers?

Comment: Your regex won't match your string `"Game No : 432543254 \n"`, there is no provision for a space between the last number and the newline. Also, the non-capture grouping `(?:Game No : )` is not necessary, why are you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-capturing group does not *capture*, but still matches the string. Besides, there is a space between the digits and the newline in your pattern, so it won't match.

To get the digits, you would use a capturing group around the digit matching pattern, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Game No : ([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(curr);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1));
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/rZiMxr)

Or, use a non-regex solution, just split with `:` and get the second item of the resulting array and trim it.